# Return sum from many records

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I have a table in `SQLite`

```
CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" {
   "product" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
   "version" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   "quantity" INTEGER,
   //etc
}
```

and some records are like

```
"product" - "01" - 1000
"product" - "01" - 1000
"product" - "02" - 4000
"product" - "02" - 1000
"product" - "03" - 3000
```

I try to make a query so I get all the sums for each product and version. In the above example the query would returned

```
"product" - "01" - 2000
"product" - "02" - 5000
"product" - "03" - 3000
```

I tried this query which returns `ambiguous column name: product`

```
SELECT product , version, SUM(quantity) AS total 
from INVENTORY 
INNER JOIN INVENTORY
       ON product AND version
GROUP BY product, version
```

Comment: The problem is you haven't used aliases, so the engine doesn't know which `product` you mean. Why do you use a self-join at all?

Comment: I am newbie to DB management, i will search for `self join` and get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT product, version, SUM(quantity) AS total 
FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY product, version
```

Comment: yeah. You don't need self join as @HoneyBadger said